# Trouble Understanding PowerShell "Help Page" Syntax

Tags: powershell

I hope this question hasn't been asked before, but I'm having trouble understanding a small part of PS Help Syntax. Microsoft's documentation on the subject has it so that optional parameters are encased in square "[]" brackets. The book I'm reading (Learn Windows PowerShell in a Month of Lunches, 3rd Ed.) says the same. The example provided by the book is to run "Get-EventLog" without any parameters, and you'll see that LogName will come up as a prompt. However, when I look at the help page for Get-EventLog, I see that -LogName is indeed in brackets, making it optional. My question is why do you get a prompt for LogName if it was optional to begin with? What step in logic am I missing here? Is "optional" in this sense only referring to the act of literally typing out "-LogName", not the entirety of the parameter (which would include the string) itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the site. A reasonable question. I think the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/appendix-a?view=powershell-7) covers this better than I could.

> The first parameter in the first parameter set of Get-EventLog is LogName. **LogName is surrounded by square brackets which means that it's a positional parameter**. In other words, specifying **the name of the parameter itself is optional** as long as it's specified in the correct position.

This basically means that you can specify one of the log names as the first parameter, as a string, and PowerShell will know that first position, Position[0], is where the `-LogName` parameter is expected.

So you can type this:

```bsh
Get-EventLog System
```

And you don't have to write it like this:

```bsh
Get-EventLog -LogName System
```